# TextBox not clickable automatically when insertafter done

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I use `insertAfter()` id block then textbox is not clickable!

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id").click(function() {
      $("#id").insertAfter($(".logo"));
    });
  });
</script>

<body>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p class="logo">This is another paragraph.</p>
  <button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>
  <div id="id">
    <form>
      <input type="text" />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's because you're destroying/recreating the `input` element on every single click. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Update the question with requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var clickedOnce = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id").click(function(){
      if(clickedOnce === false) {
        $("#id").insertAfter($(".logo"));
        clickedOnce = true;
      }
    });
});
</script>
<body>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p class="logo">This is another paragraph.</p>
  <button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>
  <div id="id">
    <form>
      <input  type="text" />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is because you when you clicked the second or more times, it is still inserting `#id` after `.logo` and it will make the textbox buggy.
You need to check if the button has been clicked once.

Answer (score 0):

It is Working Check.

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var moved = false;
     $("#id").click(function() {
          if(!moved) {
          $("#id").insertAfter($(".logo"));
          moved = true;
           }
        });    
      });

</script>

<body>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p class="logo">This is another paragraph.</p>
  <button>Clone all p elements, and append them to the body element</button>
  <div id="id">
    <form>
      <input type="text"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```